# How do I configure SaltStack to transfer a file (or install a package) for the first time?

Tags: devops, salt-stack, configuration-management

I am running two instances of RedHat.  I have SaltMaster installed on one machine and SaltMinion installed on another.   I am using a free version of Salt.  I want to test SaltStack to do a basic configuration management task.  If it can transfer a file from SaltMaster to SaltMinion, that would be great.  If it can install Apache web server on SaltMinion, that would be great.  Either task will help me learn.  My learning goal is semi-flexible.

I can use `salt '*' test.ping`.  The response is `True`.  I tried this command:  `salt '*' state.apply`

I got this error:

```
> hostname.fqdn:
>     Data failed to compile:
> ----------
>     No matching salt environment for environment 'qa' found
> ----------
>     No matching sls found for 'qa1' in env 'qa'
> ----------
>     No matching sls found for 'base1' in env 'base'
> ----------
>     No matching salt environment for environment 'dev' found
> ----------
>     Specified SLS base1 in saltenv dev is not available on the salt master or through a configured fileserver
```

I modified the /etc/salt/master file.  I uncommented these lines:

```
fileserver_backend:
  - git
  - roots
```

I tried this command again: `salt '*' state.apply`

I received this error:

```
> [ERROR   ] Error parsing configuration file: /etc/salt/master -
> expected '<document start>', but found '<block mapping start>'   in
> "<string>", line 547, column 1:
>     fileserver_backend:
>     ^ [ERROR   ] Error parsing configuration file: /etc/salt/master - expected '<document start>', but found '<block mapping start>'   in
> "<string>", line 547, column 1:
>     fileserver_backend:
>     ^
```

I have been following these directions here:
https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/states_pt1.html

I created a `webserver.sls` file.

I inserted these lines as the content:

```
apache:                 # ID declaration
  pkg:                  # state declaration
    - installed         # function declaration
```

I do not see how the three lines in the directions above would be enough to configure SaltStack to work.  Where would the apache installation media need to be?  Where would the transfer happen from?  Am I supposed to download the media to SaltMaster?  I would assume so.  But where would I put it?  I have a satellite server for yum commands to work.

Alternatively, how do I get SaltStack to transfer a file from SaltMaster to SaltMinion?

Answer (score 0):

The first error (`[...]No matching sls found for 'qa1' in env 'qa'[...]`) indicates that you have configured a lot of different environments (`file_roots`), which are not present on your master's filesystem. Your approach to solve this goes in the correct direction, but leads to this error:

> [ERROR ] Error parsing configuration file: /etc/salt/master - expected '', but found '' in "", line 547, column 1: fileserver_backend: ^ [ERROR ] Error parsing configuration file: /etc/salt/master - expected '', but found '' in "", line 547, column 1: fileserver_backend: ^

You should no longer be able to `test.ping` your minion, as the salt master should not run anymore, does it? To solve it just read the error message. It tells you with which point in your salt master configuration file salt is unhappy.

The `fileserver_backend` configures which types of backend should be available. You should check the `file_roots` configuration to actually define which roots are available. Roots refer to salt states folders in your filesystem.

A very simple config might look like that:

```
file_roots:
  base:
  - /srv/salt
```

It assumes that `/srv/salt` is the root of your state tree - which effectively means, that your `webserver.sls` should be located in this folder.

Your `webserver.sls` looks promising - it should install apache2 on a minion, when you apply it.

Managing **configuration** files on the master and transferring them to the minions is something salt can easily achieve. A simple state might look like:

```
/etc/myawesomeconfigurationfile.conf:
  file.managed:
    source: salt://myawesomefile  # refers to /srv/salt/myawesomefile
    user: root
    group: root
    mode: 640
```

You also asked for *media* files that you want to manage. If you talk about application related data it is not a good idea to use salt to move them around. IMO other approaches like NFS, GlusterFS or anything else that decouples user content from your application would be a better approach.